# In array of object, we need take same related id and pushing in one object

Tags: javascript

```
array of objects from database
        [
          {​​​​​​​
            campaign_definition_id: '125',
            campaign_activity_id: '90',
            member_id: 127863,
            template_name: null,
            template_id: '8498'
          }​​​​​​​,
          {​​​​​​​
            campaign_definition_id: '125',
            campaign_activity_id: '90',
            member_id: 130349,
            template_name: null,
            template_id: '8498'
          }​​​​​​​,
          {​​​​​​​
            campaign_definition_id: '125',
            campaign_activity_id: '90',
            member_id: 172867,
            template_name: null,
            template_id: '8498'
          }​​​​​​​,
            {​​​​​​​
            campaign_definition_id: '125',
            campaign_activity_id: '91',
            member_id: 127863,
            template_name: null,
            template_id: '9093'
          }​​​​​​​,
          {​​​​​​​
            campaign_definition_id: '125',
            campaign_activity_id: '91',
            member_id: 130349,
            template_name: null,
            template_id: '9093'
          }​​​​​​​,
          {​​​​​​​
            campaign_definition_id: '125',
            campaign_activity_id: '91',
            member_id: 172867,
            template_name: null,
            template_id: '9093'
          }​​​​​​​
        ]
```

Expected Result:

```
[
 {​​​​​​​
    campaign_definition_id: '125',
    campaign_activity_id: '90',
    member_id: [127863,130349,172867],
    template_name: null,
    template_id: '8498'
 
 }​​​​​​​
 {​​​​​​​
 campaign_definition_id: '125',
    campaign_activity_id: '91',
    member_id: [127863,130349,172867],
    template_name: null,
    template_id: '9093'
  }​​​​​​​
]
```

Hi, from the database the data is coming in  array of objects, i need to take the same campaign_activity_id and put it in object and for that related campaign_activity_id , i need  to take the member_id and push it to array, i have shown the expected result in above .please any one help me.....

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = data.reduce((acc, s) => {
    if (acc[s.campaign_activity_id]) {
        if (typeof acc[s.campaign_activity_id].member_id === 'number') {
            acc[s.campaign_activity_id].member_id = [
              acc[s.campaign_activity_id].member_id, s.member_id
            ];
        } else if (Array.isArray(acc[s.campaign_activity_id].member_id)) {
          acc[s.campaign_activity_id].member_id = [
            ...acc[s.campaign_activity_id].member_id,
            s.member_id,
          ];
        }
    } else {
        acc[s.campaign_activity_id] = s;
    }
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```